# how to normalize subarrays in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `data` of shape: [128, 64, 64, 64], and I wonder what's the best way to normalized each of the 128 slices into range [0.0, 1.0]. I understand i could use np.max(data[0,...]), np.max(data[1,...])... np.max(data[127,...]) to compute max values in each slice, but wonder if i could do this more efficiently.

Essentially something like this:

```
data_min = np.min(data[:,...])
data_max = np.max(data[:,...])
norm_data = (data[:,...] - data_min)/(data_max - data_min)
```

The result should still have shape [128, 64, 64, 64]
But i haven't figured out which particular min/max functions and options to use to obtain the results.

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: But the original shape was `[128,64,64,64]`?

Comment: just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the min and max values, while keeping dimensions to help us with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) later on when we use those to normalize input data using the normalization formula, like so -

```
mins = data.min(axis=(1,2,3), keepdims=True)
maxs = data.max(axis=(1,2,3), keepdims=True)
norm_data = (data-mins)/(maxs-mins)
```

Comment: This seems to normalize the entire ndarray, while I wanted to normalized per subarray along the first dimension, as in the question: data[0,...], then data[1,...], etc. how to change accordingly?

Comment: cool~! it works now. 'keepdims' seems critical in this situation. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.vectorize` to apply a function over all elements of an array:

```
def norm(element):
    return (element - data_min) / (data_max - data_min)

ndnorm = np.vectorize(norm)

data_min = data.min()
data_max = data.max()

norm_data = ndnorm(data)
```

Comment: Do you mind rewriting this to normalize the subarrays along the first dimension? interested in seeing how vectorize() works

Comment: Information about `np.vectorize` can be easily found in [numpy reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). To normalize each subarray along the first dimension, you can apply the same function over each subarray in a for loop. To do it in one line, add `data_min` and `data_max` to the arguments of `norm` and: `norm_data = np.array([ndnorm(subarr, subarr.min(), subarr.max()) for subarr in data])`